# Is there a way to set UI elements beneath a video player?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making a 2D game in Unity that plays a video when the game begins. The problem is that the UI is above the video and because this is my first time using Unity, I have no idea of how to fix this.

I've tried to set the video player's render mode to "camera near plane", but the UI is still above the video.

Is there any way to set the UI elements beneath the video player, or to hide the UI elements until the video stops playing?

Comment: easiest way is to disable temporarily the ui canvas by setting setactive to false. then back again after the video stops playing.

Answer (score 1):

## How to render VideoPlayer beneath UI

You can render your video player on a `RawImage` by referencing a `Render Texture` on your `VideoPlayer` and then referencing it on the `RawImage` you wish to render it on. This way your video player essentially becomes an another UI element which you can sort around however you want with the other UI - place it below the other UI elements in the `Hierarchy` to render it on top of the other ones.

### Example

Here's how things might look in the `Inspector` for the VideoPlayer, RawImage and the Hierarchy.

[image]

## How to hide UI while VideoPlayer is playing

You can disable your `Canvas` element that contains all of your UI by using `.SetActive()` method. All you need to do is attach the necessary behavior by subscribing to `VideoPlayer` events - `started` and `loopPointReached`.

### Example

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class HideTargetWhilePlayingVideo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject target = null;

    [SerializeField]
    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer = null;

    private void Start()
    {
        videoPlayer.started += OnVideoStarted;
        videoPlayer.loopPointReached += OnVideoStopped;
    }

    private void OnVideoStarted(VideoPlayer source)
    {
        target.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void OnVideoStopped(VideoPlayer source)
    {
        target.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (videoPlayer)
        {
            videoPlayer.started -= OnVideoStarted;
            videoPlayer.loopPointReached -= OnVideoStopped;
        }
    }
}
```